# Telegram Bot - Why cant i receive any updates? api connecting ok

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram

im trying to create a script to monitor a telegram channel and forward messages that meet a set criteria to my private channel. I have updated all admin accesses etc in the private, it is succesfully connecting to the API but not receiving any updates? Any help would be most appreciated.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, MessageHandler, CallbackContext, filters

# Set up detailed logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

TOKEN = 'Bot_Token'
SOURCE_CHANNEL_USERNAME = 'Source_Channel'  # Replace with your source channel's username
DESTINATION_CHANNEL_ID = -'Destination_Channel'  # Replace with your destination channel's numeric ID

async def forward_hot_token(update, context):
    try:
        message = update.message
        if message and message.chat.username == SOURCE_CHANNEL_USERNAME.lstrip('@'):
            logging.info(f"Received message from {SOURCE_CHANNEL_USERNAME}: {message.text}")

            if "X" in message.caption or "Y" in message.caption:
                logging.info("Criteria met. Forwarding message...")
                await context.bot.copy_message(chat_id=DESTINATION_CHANNEL_ID, from_chat_id=message.chat_id,
                                               message_id=message.message_id)

                contract_number = extract_contract_number(message.caption)
                if contract_number:
                    logging.info(f"Sending contract number: {contract_number}")
                    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=DESTINATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                                                   text=f"Contract Number: {contract_number}")
            else:
                logging.info("Message does not meet the forwarding criteria.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in forward_hot_token: {e}")

def extract_contract_number(caption):
    words = caption.split()
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == 42 and all(c in "abcdef0123456789" for c in word.lower()):
            return word
    return None

async def log_all_updates(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    logging.info(f"Received an update: {update}")

async def main():
    logging.info("Starting bot...")
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()

    # Define the filter for messages with captions
    caption_filter = filters.Caption()

    # Create a MessageHandler instance using the new filter syntax
    hot_token_handler_instance = MessageHandler(caption_filter, forward_hot_token)
    application.add_handler(hot_token_handler_instance)

    # Handler to log all updates
    all_updates_handler = MessageHandler(filters.ALL, log_all_updates)
    application.add_handler(all_updates_handler)

    # Start the application
    await application.initialize()

    try:
        # Keep the bot running
        logging.info("Bot is now running. Press Ctrl+C to exit.")
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info("Bot stopped by user.")
    finally:
        # Ensure the application shuts down gracefully
        await application.shutdown()
        logging.info("Bot has been shut down.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())`
```

I have checked telegram api connection, and bot initiliazing which is all fine. I have tried to remove the message checks so it just forwards all messages. Ive setup test channels, and test messages direct. Nothing is picked up